# Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading ng2-appinsights

Tags: angular, typescript, node-modules, azure-application-insights

I am trying to implement the application insights in my Angular 2 application using ng2-appinsights.

For that I followed [this link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-appinsights).

This is the code I wrote in my `package.json`.

```
{
"name": "angular-quickstart",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation,   supplemented   with testing support",
"scripts": {
"build": "tsc -p src/",
"build:watch": "tsc -p src/ -w",
"build:e2e": "tsc -p e2e/",
"serve": "lite-server -c=bs-config.json",
"serve:e2e": "lite-server -c=bs-config.e2e.json",
"prestart": "npm run build",
"start": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"npm run serve\"",
"pree2e": "npm run build:e2e",
"e2e": "concurrently \"npm run serve:e2e\" \"npm run protractor\" --kill-others --success first",
"preprotractor": "webdriver-manager update",
"protractor": "protractor protractor.config.js",
"pretest": "npm run build",
"test": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
"pretest:once": "npm run build",
"test:once": "karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
"lint": "tslint ./src/**/*.ts -t verbose"
},
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "MIT",
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "~2.4.0",
"@angular/compiler": "~2.4.0",
"@angular/core": "~2.4.0",
"@angular/forms": "~2.4.0",
"@angular/http": "~2.4.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.0",
"@angular/router": "~3.4.0",

"angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.4",
"systemjs": "0.19.40",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"rxjs": "5.0.1",
"zone.js": "^0.7.4",

"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
"crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
"aes": "0.1.0",
"ng2-appinsights": "^0.3.0",
"applicationinsights-js": "^1.0.8"
},
"devDependencies": {
"concurrently": "^3.2.0",
"lite-server": "^2.2.2",
"typescript": "~2.0.10",

"canonical-path": "0.0.2",
"tslint": "^3.15.1",
"lodash": "^4.16.4",
"jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
"karma": "^1.3.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
"karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
"karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"protractor": "~4.0.14",
"rimraf": "^2.5.4",

"@types/node": "^6.0.46",
"@types/jasmine": "2.5.36"
},
"repository": {}
}
```

This is the code I wrote in `systemjs.config.js`

```
  (function (global) {
  System.config({
  paths: {
  // paths serve as alias
  'npm:': 'node_modules/'
  },
  // map tells the System loader where to look for things
  map: {
  // our app is within the app folder
  app: 'app',

  // angular bundles
  '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
  '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
  '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
  '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
  '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
  '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
  '@angular/router/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router-upgrade.umd.js',
  '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
  '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',
  '@angular/upgrade/static': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade-static.umd.js',

  // other libraries
  'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
  'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
  'cryptojs': 'npm:crypto-js/crypto-js.js',
  'ng2-appinsights':'npm:ng2-appinsights'
},
// packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
packages: {
  app: {
    main: './main.js',
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  },
  rxjs: {
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  },
  'ng2-appinsights': {
      main: './main.js',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
}
});
})(this);
```

I did not find out which one is the main class for ng2-appinsgihts, see the below image for more information of ng2-appinsights installed in my node_modules folder.

[image]

I am trying to import the respective application insights modules, by using the below line of code.

```
import { AppInsightsModule } from 'ng2-appinsights';
```

After added the above code and run my application in local machine, I always got the error:

> Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3997/ng2-appinsights

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to declare the package in your systemjs.config.js

Add this:

```
map: {
    ...
    //other librairies
    'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
    'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
    'cryptojs': 'npm:crypto-js/crypto-js.js',
    'ng2-appinsights':           'npm:ng2-appinsights'
```

And this

```
packages: {
    ...
    'ng2-appinsights': {
        //main: 'Path to the main of ng2-appinsights'
        main: 'bundles/ng2-appinsights.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated the code in systemjs.config.js file but still also I faced the same issue. can you please see my updated code in my above question.

Comment: Go see in your 'node_modules' folder the name of the main class of ng2-appinsights. Are you sure that is 'main.js' ?

Comment: I did not find which one is the name of main class of ng2-appinsights. can you please see my updated question once for more information.

Comment: Give a try to './index.js'

Comment: I already tried with that above line of code but still I got the same error.

Comment: Did you try to put node_modes/ before the index.js ? Please try several combinations

Comment: I tried with these two scenarios   'ng2-appinsights': {
          main: 'node_modules/ng2-appinsights/index.js',
          defaultExtension: 'js'
      },   'ng2-appinsights': {
          main: 'node_modules/index.js',
          defaultExtension: 'js'
      } but still I got the same error.

Comment: Then it's not index.js :) Try with  'ng2-appinsights': { main: 'node_modules/ng2-appinsights/bundles/ng2-appinsights.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }

Comment: I tried with the above line of code and some other scenarios but still I got the same error.

Comment: Did you put this line `import { AppInsightsModule } from 'ng2-appinsights';` in you app module and add it to imports `imports : [
        ...,
        AppInsightsModule,
]`

Comment: Yes. I added it into appmodule.ts

Comment: If you did all this, I don't know what's going on.. Last thing, try npm cache clear; npm install. Then I don't have any idea left

Comment: Last try maybe: Try with 'ng2-appinsights': { main: './bundles/ng2-appinsights.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }

Comment: But still I faced the same issue.

Comment: Then try to post an issue on ng2-appinsights' github

Comment: Thanks, I resolved the above error by putting these lines of code  'ng2-appinsights': {
          main: 'bundles/ng2-appinsights.js',
          defaultExtension: 'js'
      }, but in your earlier comment you mention wrong path of the main class of ng2-appinsights.